# Нужно ли обособление в текущем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

"А вообще-то, при определённых условиях, я бы не отказался"

Comment: Зря Вы откатили мою правку, *Xenrik_123*! Теперь в шапке нет ни определенных условий, ни изюминки, а имеется просто обыкновенное и странно *текущее предложение*. И точка в конце предложения исчезла (а это ошибка). И метка "запятая" — тоже (а она никак не была лишней, потому что обособление может происходить и с помощью тире).

Answer (score 3):

Решение задач по пунктуации лучше начинать с интонационного анализа.

Рассмотрим два варианта:

(1)  Простое предложение без обособления: ***А вообще-то при определЁнных условиях  // я бы не отказАлся.***

(2)  Обособленный оборот: ***А вообщЕ-то,  при определённых услОвиях,  я бы не отказАлся.***

В принципе **оба варианты возможны**.

В предложении (1) оборот выделен логическим ударением, а в предложении (2) этот оборот обособляется (вставочная интонация).

С точки зрения **смысла** выбор зависит **от контекста**.

В первом случае, вероятно, **об условиях** уже шла речь, поэтому оборот включен в основной состав предложения. Во втором случае говорится о согласии, **но при определенных условиях**, которые затем могут быть названы.

Соответственно, выбор варианта  делается автором и проверяется по произношению.

В конечном итоге **решение** можно сформулировать так: оборот **обособляется,** если имеет значение **уточнения**, и не обособляется при отсутствии такого значения. Вариант с уточнением кажется более вероятным, поэтому при отсутствии контекста **оборот лучше обособить.**

У Розенталя рассматривается эта тема : § 22. Уточняющие члены предложения http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

Но там дан материал для трех видов обстоятельств (места, времени, образа действия), а в данном случае обстоятельства  имеют значение условия.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Спасибо, вы меня тоже иногда читаете – вот уж неожиданность.  Действительно,  мне  нужен хороший редактор, а то у меня внимание рассеяно по нескольким темам. Вот и  система   обругала роботом, когда я на это поле скопировала (из черновика) ответ на другой вопрос.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Sharon! Читаю не иногда, а постоянно! :)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Умеете вы нравиться, где только научились. И обмануть меня не трудно, что уж там говорить…Хотя нет, пусть будет лучше трудно. Поэтому свой следующий вопрос я посвящаю вам. Пожалуйста, ответьте на него, всё равно же читать будете.